# Optimality of prefix codes

Tags: huffman-coding

In [Introduction to Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms), when talking about prefix code for Huffman encoding, it says that:

> Although we won’t prove it here, a prefix code can always achieve the optimal data compression among any character code...

How can we prove such a claim? My first thought was in the direction of representing the encoded codes in form of trees, and hence we can prove that, but how do we prove this for any prefix code (as this is not talking about Huffman encoding only but any prefix code in general)?

Comment: The claim is not true for **any** prefix code. It is saying that there exists a prefix code that achieves optimal data compression.

Comment: Introduction to Algorithms has several authors.

Comment: They might be referring to the [Kraft–McMillan inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraft%E2%80%93McMillan_inequality#Proof_of_the_general_case) for uniquely decodable codes.